# Trouble with combox and textfield alignment

Tags: java, extjs, combobox, playframework, textfield

So I am trying to add a combobox that has 2 values on the same line as my text field, but am having trouble doing so.

This is what it looks like right now:
[image]

I want to be able to move the combobox to the left of the 2 textfields that I have.

This is the code that I have for my combobox which I have placed outside of my Formpanel:

```
var cbTemplate = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: false,
    width: 125,
    hideTrigger:true,
    allowBlank: true,
    displayField: 'val',

});

// ComboBox for switching status
var carWeightData={lstValueRecords: [{val: 'Item 1'},{val: 'Item 2'}]};
var cbCombo = jQuery.extend(true, {}, cbTemplate);
cbCombo.id = 'cbCarWeight';
cbCombo.name = 'cbCarWeight';
cbCombo.emptyText = 'Please Select';
cbCombo.hideTrigger = false;
cbCombo.mode = 'local';
cbCombo.triggerAction = 'all';
cbCombo.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    data: comboData,
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'lstValueRecords',
        fields: [
                    {name: 'val', mapping: 'val'}
                ]
    })
});
```

So I am trying to add a combobox that has 2 values on the same line as my text field, but am having trouble doing so.

This is what it looks like right now: combobox

I want to be able to move the combobox to the left of the 2 textfields that I have.

This is the code that I have for my combobox which I have placed outside of my Formpanel:

```
var cbTemplate = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: false,
    width: 125,
    hideTrigger:true,
    allowBlank: true,
    displayField: 'val',

});

// ComboBox for switching status
var carWeightData={lstValueRecords: [{val: 'Item 1'},{val: 'Item 2'}]};
var cbCombo = jQuery.extend(true, {}, cbTemplate);
cbCombo.id = 'cbCarWeight';
cbCombo.name = 'cbCarWeight';
cbCombo.emptyText = 'Please Select';
cbCombo.hideTrigger = false;
cbCombo.mode = 'local';
cbCombo.triggerAction = 'all';
cbCombo.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    data: comboData,
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'lstValueRecords',
        fields: [
                    {name: 'val', mapping: 'val'}
                ]
    })
});
```

This is my textfield portion which is inside the FormPanel and inside a column:

```
columnWidth:.6,
layout: 'form',
items: [
cbCombo,{
  xtype: 'container',
  layout: 'hbox',
  hideLabel: true,
  labelStyle: 'width: 105px',
  fieldLabel: 'Combo Data',
  anchor: '90%',
  items:[{
     xtype:'textfield',
     name: 'locationId1',
     flex: 12
  },{                       
      xtype: 'label',
      margins: '0 0 0 5',
      text:'-',
      flex: 1
  },{
      xtype:'textfield',
      name: 'locationId2',
      flex: 12
  }]
```

}]

Is there anyway that I could move the combobox down to be next to the texfield?

Please help!

Comment: You've just asked that question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498670/trouble-putting-combox-on-the-same-line-as-a-textfield, its not playframework related

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do the same as your text fields?

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        // combobox configuration
    },{
        xtype:'textfield',
        name: 'locationId1',
        flex: 12
    },
    ...
]
```

Nothing prevents you from putting an instantiated component in there, either:

```
items: [
    new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        // combobox configuration
    }),
    {
        xtype:'textfield',
        name: 'locationId1',
        flex: 12
    },
    ...
]
```

Extending an Ext component with jQuery is something I would refrain myself from doing, however o_O

Comment: I orginally has the combobox just like xtype:combo like you mentioned. However, I was unabel to figure out how to load my 2 values. I would just get a blank combobox.

Comment: So I fixed the issue I had the defined cbCombo in the wrong placement. I ended up just placing it right above  items:[{
     xtype:'textfield',
     name: 'locationId1',
     flex: 12
  }